# Why does Keras sometimes learn nothing

Tags: keras

I work with Keras for two (or so) years now and I have approached a number of different regression and classification problems using Keras.

I recognized that my models sometimes learn nothing, meaning that they cannot beat a naive Bassline (e.g. 50% accuracy in binary classification).

Note that the same (or very similar) model did learn much (!) better in previous runs or when I restart the learning process. So there seems to be quite a random element in each model training run.

Does anyone know where these effect comes from?

Comment: Could be very many things. Among them: is your learning rate too high? if you bounce around the parameter space too much, then it is indeed pretty random whether you end up in a meaningless part of it, or happen to land in a useful part of it.

Comment: @SeanOwen: No, I use a low learning rate. The model (with exactly the same parameters) did learn very well but (sometimes) lingers around 50% accuracy in a binary setting. This is what I wonder about: why the huge difference in learning with same parameter?

Comment: Maybe you have a random initializer for the weights that's not quite suitable? Really hard to say without more info.